Safari New Tab Extension Displays White Screen During Loading
I developed a new tab extension for Safari. However, I'm facing an issue where there's a brief white screen every time I open a new tab, followed by the loading of HTML and JS files. I want it to work seamlessly without any delays, just like the default new tab.
Is this possible
I checked the developer settings, I noticed that there's a "-" value for delays for all of them. The problem doesn't seem to be with the file size or the code itself, as I encountered the same issue even when testing with a blank page.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
